# jython Can't list error

Tags: java, python, jython

I am trying to convert a python class into Java byte code with Jython (on mac osx lion)

> ./jython -m compileall /Users/owengerig/Downloads/Code\
>   Downloads/cryptPYTHON.py

but get this error, which gives no indication of whats wrong

> Listing /Users/owengerig/Downloads/Code Downloads/cryptPYTHON.py ...
>   Can't list /Users/owengerig/Downloads/Code Downloads/cryptPYTHON.py

How my python class is setup ([used this post as example](http://wiki.python.org/jython/ReplaceJythonc)):

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import os

class Crypticle(CryptInterface):
    """Authenticated encryption class

     * @param string    $key      base64-encoded encryption key
     * @param integer   $key_len  length of raw key in bits

    Encryption algorithm: AES-CBC
    Signing algorithm: HMAC-SHA256
    """

    AES_BLOCK_SIZE = 16

    @JAVA
    def __init__(self, key_string, key_size=192):
        assert not key_size % 8
        self.key = self.extract_key(key_string, key_size)
        self.key_size = key_size

    @classmethod
    def generate_key_string(cls, key_size=192):
        key = os.urandom(key_size / 8)
        return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(key))

    @classmethod
    def extract_key(cls, key_string, key_size):
        key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(str(key_string))
        assert len(key) == key_size / 8, "invalid key"
        return key

    @JAVA(String, String)    
    def encrypt(self, data):
        """encrypt data with AES-CBC"""
        aes_key = self.key
        pad = self.AES_BLOCK_SIZE - len(data) % self.AES_BLOCK_SIZE
        data = data + pad * chr(pad)
        iv_bytes = os.urandom(self.AES_BLOCK_SIZE)
        cypher = AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv_bytes)
        data = iv_bytes + cypher.encrypt(data)
        data_str = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(data))
        return data_str

    @JAVA(String, String)  
    def decrypt(self, data_str):
        """decrypt data with AES-CBC"""
        aes_key = self.key
        data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data_str)
        iv_bytes = data[:self.AES_BLOCK_SIZE]
        data = data[self.AES_BLOCK_SIZE:]
        cypher = AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv_bytes)
        data = cypher.decrypt(data)
        return data[:-ord(data[-1])]
```

Also tried this code (per comments below) but go the same error:

```
class Employee(Object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.first = "Josh"
      self.last  = "Juneau"
      self.id = "myempid"

   def getEmployeeFirst(self):
      return self.first

   def getEmployeeLast(self):
      return self.last

   def getEmployeeId(self):
      return self.id
```

Comment: Does Jython work for you for a smaller program?

Comment: no, good call.  didnt think to check that.  I used just the plan example is the link above class Employee(Object): and stil the same error

Comment: Note that by "smaller program", I mean something like a "Hello, world" program that doesn't involve crypto stuff. That's usually the first thing that you would try, especially if you're having problems at this point.

Comment: check the update i posted, the code at the bottom is very simple and is what i tried to convert, but still the same error

Comment: Is it possible that jython is foolish with spaces in the path?

Comment: nope, moved the file into the jython directory so the command was just jython -m compileall sample.py and still the same error

Comment: What jython version are you using?

Comment: 2.5.2 is the version i downloaded and installed

Comment: Ok, so far I've determined that the same problem occurs using 2.5.3 on linux ubuntu. trying to find a fix.

Comment: Figured it out :) It was deceptively simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-m compileall takes a directory, not a filename. So you need to execute the following:

```
./jython -m compileall /Users/owengerig/Downloads/Code\ Downloads/
```

**Long Explanation**

If you open *jythondirectory*/Lib/compileall.py:

```
try:
    names = os.listdir(dir)
except os.error:
    print "Can't list", dir
    names = []
```

os.listdir() throws an error if it isn't passed a directory as its argument. Since this is the function used to compile the command-line arguments, and the main() function does not check if the arguments are directories, this will fail.

```
        for dir in args:
            if not compile_dir(dir, maxlevels, ddir,
                               force, rx, quiet):
                success = 0
```

**/Long Explanation**

Comment: thank you, that was it.  can we meet in chat for a followup question (i guess the python chat room)?

Comment: @owengerig That works fine, I'll be in and out of the python chat for a couple of hours